# Stuck at understanding the proof on why every irreducible representation of a finite abelian group is one dimensional

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

The proof presented in my reading material is the following

> Suppose that the base field is the field of complex numbers. Let $(\rho, V)$ be an irreducible representation of a finite abelian group $G$. Then, $\forall g, h \in G: \rho(g)\rho(h) = \rho(gh) = \rho(hg) = \rho(h)\rho(g)$. **Thus, by applying Schur's lemma we see that $\rho(g) = \lambda_g * I$ for some $\lambda_g \in \mathbb{C}$.**

And the rest is important for this question. I'm currently stuck at understanding why the fact that any interwining map $T:V\to V$ is of the form $T = \lambda * I$ leads to the fact that $\rho(g) = \lambda_g * I$, when an interwining map of two representations $\rho_1:G\to \mathrm{Aut}(V_1), \rho_2G:\to\mathrm{Aut}(V_2)$ is defined as such a linear mapping $T:V_1 \to V_2$ that $T\circ \rho_1(g) = \rho_2(g) \circ T$? Applying the $T$ given by Schur's lemma to $\rho$ yields $\rho(g) \circ T = \rho(g) \circ \lambda * I = \lambda * \rho(g) \circ I = T\circ \rho(g) = \lambda * I \circ \rho(g)$, and I don't see how you can conclude from this that $\rho(g) = \lambda * I$.

Comment: I usually understand this in an old-fashioned way: "commuting diagonalisable linear transformations are simultaneously diagonalisable". So there is a basis of $V$ of simultaneous eigenvectors for all the elements of $G$. Etc.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I'm sorry but as I'm quite new to representation theory (and struggling immensely), you are going to have to ELI5 to me your comment, if you want it to be accepted :D. Due to the given statement it feels to me that there is some simple algebraic proof for the *we see that* part, but I don't know what it is, and I doubt that I will by myself alone.

Comment: We are just applying Schur's Lemma with $T = \rho$. The fact that $G$ is abelian implies that $T=\rho$ is an intertwining map.